# Определение текущего времени

Tags: java

Как в java вывести на экран текущее время?

Answer (score 1):

Разумеется, [Calendar.getInstance()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#getInstance%28%29).

```
new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy.MM.dd HH:mm:ss").format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
```

Как вывести строку на экран, пояснять, надеюсь, не надо.